# Is there a way to read a file object using Fog and CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, fog

I'm using CarrierWave and Fog to store attachments to an ActiveRecord model on S3. I can use them to generate the URL, but I can't seem to locate any method to actually read a file.

Is this something that the Fog gem will even do, or do I need to use the S3 gem for that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the `read` method on the uploader object. If we have a model called MyModel which has a field called `attachment` which was added using CarrierWave's `mount_uploader` method, we can do the following:

```
obj = MyModel.first
contents = obj.attachment.read
```

This will get the actual contents of the file. Check out [this doc](http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/Storage/S3/File.html#M000136).

Comment: No, this does *not* work on locally stored files with a local_root set.

Answer (score 3):

You just require `open-uri`

```
require 'open-uri'
file_contents = open(string_url) {|f| f.read }
```